# How to see properties by default?

Tags: org-mode

I can toggle the visibility of text under a heading by pressing `TAB`, it doesn't show the contents of the properties drawer. I want to look at properties often. Is there a way to have Emacs expand the properties drawer whenever the text under a heading is shown? What other ways of showing the properties easily and maybe automatically are there?

Comment: I few years ago, I modified `org-cycle-internal-local` in my own setup:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17492723/2112489  The `org-mode` developers changes things so often that I gave up trying to follow its current development ...  And, of course, no one except for me likes to modify the sacred functions directly ...  You may also wish to customize the start-up visibility setting for `org-mode`:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html